# WordPress auto posting

Tags: php, database, wordpress

I have a WordPress blog in which I need to add multiple posts. Is it possible that if I can directly insert data into the table? I know PHP but I am new to WordPress. So any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Look into a CSV importer plugin. You can easily create an Excel file and turn it into a CSV to import. WordPress should offer something similar under the Tools section.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Wordpress Importer plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-importer/) as suggested by WPZA.

And, as you know `php` so there's another option available for you. You can use wordpress [wp_insert_post](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/) function to insert posts programmatically.

Here is the sample code:

```
// Create post
$id = wp_insert_post(array(
  'post_title'    => $title,
  'post_content'  => $content,
  'post_date'     => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
  'post_author'   => $user_id,
  'post_type'     => 'post',
  'post_status'   => 'publish',
));
if ($id) {

  // Use this code, if requires to categories posts
  // wp_set_post_terms($id, wp_create_category('My Category'), 'category');

  // Add meta data, if required
  // add_post_meta($id, 'meta_key', $metadata);

} else {
  echo "WARNING: Failed to insert post into WordPress\n";
}
```

**Easy to follow Steps:**

1. Prepare data in CSV file OR directly in php arrays
2. Read CSV file using [fgetcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) (if applicable)
3. Put `wp_insert_post` method inside a function.
4. Iterate through all data using [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)
5. Call the function and pass params

Hope it helps! :)